# Finding an optimal strategy for a combinatorial sequential game

Tags: co.combinatorics, pr.probability, probability-distributions, game-theory, recreational-mathematics

We are given a set $\{p_1, p_2, \ldots, p_n\}$ of players and a set of $\{\ell_1, \ell_2, \ldots, \ell_n\}$ of locations, where $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Each location can be either free or occupied, and each user can be either looking for a free location or s/he has already occupied a location. The goal of each player is to occupy a free location, and they cannot to communicate with each other. Finally, each player $p_i$ knows the total number $n$ of players/locations, but does *not* know her/his own index $i$. Each player must use the **same (randomized) strategy**.

---

The game consists of a series of rounds. Initially all locations are free. At each round $r_1, r_2, \ldots$, each player $p_i$ who has not occupied a location yet, selects an integer $j\in\{1, 2, \ldots, n\}$ and attempts to occupy $\ell_j$. For each of such players, only two mutually exclusive events are possible:

- If $\ell_j$ is *free* and during the current round *no other player* choses $j$, then $p_i$ occupies $\ell_j$ starting from the current round;
- $p_i$ does not occupy $\ell_j$.

In both cases, each player receives only one bit of information corresponding to the realization of either the former or the latter event. Hence, if two or more players select the same location $\ell_j$ during the same round, no player can occupy $\ell_j$ until the next round (without knowing if it was already occupied in a previous round or there is a conflict in the attempt of occupying it).

---

What is the *expected* minimum number of rounds necessary to occupy all locations (where the expectation is taken over the strategy randomization)? What is the corresponding strategy?

Comment: By "each player does not know his/her own index $i$, and the players cannot communicate" do you mean that each player must follow the same strategy? Or is it that each player's strategy must be symmetric over the locations (but the strategy may differ from player to player)? If you allow any strategies then of course player $i$ choosing location $i$ on the first round is good. If everyone must use the same strategy, then any deterministic strategy fails for ever (all players always choose the same location) - but your last paragraph suggests that some determinstic strategies are plausible.

Comment: Thank you, you are right about the misleading sentence on the (possible) determinism of the strategy, because the strategy *must* be randomized. Now I edit that part of the question. However, I do not understand your statement "[...] if you allow any strategies then of course player $i$ choosing location $i$ on the first round is good" because, for instance, player $p_1$ does not know her/him index ($1$ in this case). Hence, it is not possible to that each player $p_i$ chooses $\ell_i$ on the first round with probability $1$. Anyway, the strategy may differ from player to player.

Comment: So, the strategy may differ from player to player, but you don't allow the strategy to depend on the index of the player. I'm still not quite sure what the constraint on the strategies is. Does every player's strategy have to be symmetric over all the locations? For example: does every player's choice in the first round have to give probability $1/n$ to each location?

Comment: I see your point @JamesMartin. Your doubt is definitely legitimate. Could you please suggest a modification of the problem which makes it non-trivial? Should all the players play the same strategy?

Comment: @JamesMartin how can I formalize the concept that no player knows the strategies of the others?

Comment: @JamesMartin OK, I see: the strategy of each player may be dependent on the round number, but must be the same.

Comment: Yes, I would suggest two different problems might be interesting: (i) the strategies must all be the same (but may treat different locations differently); (ii) the strategies may be different for different players, but everyone's strategy must be symmetric over the locations (so indeed everyone's choice of location on round 1 is uniformly random, but thereafter maybe some players are more likely to stick in the same place several rounds in a row, and others are more likely to jump around).

Comment: For example for n=2 the best strategy of type (ii) is for one player to always switch after round 1 and the other to always stay in the same place. For higher n there are different notions of symmetry over the locations you could consider. You could ask for the strategies to be invariant under any permutation of the locations; or something weaker like that they are invariant under rotations. The second case would allow for example some players to search clockwise, while others search anticlockwise.

Comment: Thank you @JamesMartin . For the moment, I would start to focus on (i). I just added a question in the "Edit section" about the problem itself:  I am now wondering whether the problem becomes more interesting if each player can always distinguish between an attempt to occupy the same location chosen by another player during the same round, and a location which was already occupied in the previous rounds.

Comment: @Let101 : Your question could be improved if you did a few calculations. For example, what is the expected waiting time if all players adopt the obvious strategy of choosing a number uniformly at random in every round? Do you have an example, for some small value of $n$, where this obvious strategy is not optimal?

Comment: @TimothyChow this is something I was thinking about. I will add it when I will find it. Thank you for your message. By the way, do you think that the problem becomes more interesting if each player can always distinguish between an attempt to occupy the same location chosen by another player during the same round, and a location which was already occupied in the previous rounds?

Comment: @Let101 : If you have no application in mind, then I would say that the problem is interesting if the solution is interesting.

Comment: @Timothy I doubt choosing a number uniform at random in each round would be optimal. Suppose that we have already reached the state where $n-1$ locations are occupied (which we of course cannot know in the real game, but let's suppose we do). Then for the $n$-th player it's better to always pick a new number than to try an older one.